# Regularexpression working for all filelds.ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

It is very Strange situation, I make a validation for password and want only numbers and minimun one Uppercase character. But this validation goes on all field and email too! On Email I have another validation. What problem? Can please write how I must make right Regularexpression for password for numbers and minimun one Uppercase and why I have problem with all fileds

```
 public class ResetPasswordViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "minimum 5")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(?i)\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b", 
        ErrorMessage = "No format Email")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "minimum 5")]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "minimum 5")]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [RegularExpression("(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])$", ErrorMessage = "minimum one 
        Uppercase and numbers")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Not compare")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password Confirm")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
```

this validation start work for Email when I introduce it for password. Why?

```
[RegularExpression("(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])$", ErrorMessage = "minimum one 
        Uppercase and numbers")]
```

Comment: Can you publish your view?

Comment: I understood, thanks, yes there was for email validation for password) Can you please help how it must be RegularExpration for numbers and one minimum character